# How to play media - saved on db as binary - on a website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a table on SQL Server 2008, I saved on it videos and audios as binary.

I have to play these media (videos and audios) on my website.
Can I do that?

Is there a way that I could request the media as a link? so I can embed it...

Any help appreciated.

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1):

They are probably other ways to do this but i'll just show mine below.

create an asp.net page (image.aspx for instance) that has no content on the page just the @page attributes... see below.

```
  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="image.aspx.cs" Inherits="image" %>
```

You code behind file might look like below:

```
public void Page_Load(object s, System.EventArgs e) 
    {
        int id = Request.QueryString["image_id"]; //assuming u are getting it from query string
        byte[] bt = GetMediaData(id); //image data from database as byte array
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "audio/mp3"; //set mimetype of appropriate media type
        Response.BinaryWrite(abt);
        Response.Flush();
     }
```

on the page that needs to use the resource:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" id="Image1" ImageUrl="image.aspx?image_id=xx" />
```

i'm sure this can be done using http handlers though.

Comment: Thank you for your helping. but my problem is with audio and video. I have embedded it on html but it has never requested the url??? it has requested only with asp image (<asp:Image ... ImageUrl="..." />)

Comment: Using the image was just an example you can use any media tag u want. you can use "<object>" and "<embed>" tags too .. all u need to do is change the source accordingly .. i could put a sample if u want .. what specific file are u showing? flv? swf?

Comment: I tried to use <object> and <embed>, but it has never requested the url?? it has just requested with <asp:image>